# Upload image from android app , save it to sql sever

Tags: android, sql-server, image-uploading

i want to build an andoid app , which will upload the image to sqlserver 
i know how to save using  ftp server,but i dont want to do in that way

is there any way that i can save directly to sql server

Thanks for your time guys

Comment: you have to write web service and convert into byte array and upload it to server

Comment: thanks ando, i am new to this , could you be able to refer me to something (tutorial or just a overview )?

Comment: http://www.codicode.com/art/upload_files_from_android_to_a_w.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to save files in the database SQL server has a column type varbinary for saving BLOB objects.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by BASE64 encoding, you will obtain a string that you'll can store it into a TEXT field in your SQL DB.

And when you want to read or view the image, you'll have only to decode the string.

Here I give you a very good [tutorial](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com.es/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html) of how to encode